# iOS change UIButton frame to it's image frame weird error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, frame

I have a strange error when trying to change UIButton's frame.
I am trying to do the following:

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and I an image editor I see that image size is 35x37, but image.size.width / height gives me 16. 
What am I doing wrong?

PS: If I double the image.size.width, then the button's frame seems ok. I thought that both image size and UIView frame are in points.

Comment: what is the scale of your image?

Comment: Stupid me. Thank you )
That was the reason

Comment: you can use preview to check it. or just log the image. any way, you fixed. Kudos.